# Queue-ing image paths for later upload

Tags: android, file-upload, arraylist, android-asynctask, queue

I'm having difficulties keeping track of my queue and uploading them at a later moment.
The upload image is a asynctask and in the postexecute a mail is going out to send the uploaded picture.

This is my UploadImage AsyncTask. I think i'm doing way too difficult and that it can be done much easier than it is right now.

```
private class UploadImageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    /**
     * Private integer which counts how many times we've tried to upload the
     * Image.
     */
    private int _counter = 0;

    private List<String> imageUploadList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        if(AppStatus.haveNetworkConnection(_context)){
            if(isPhotoTaken()){
                dialog = new ProgressDialog(Step4.this);
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.uploadingMessage));
                dialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.uploadingTitle));
                dialog.show();
            }
        }
    }

    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        init();
        postData();
        return null;
    }
    public void init(){
        _counter = 0;
        _beenHere = true;
        for(String path : imageUploadList){
            Debug.out("Path: "+path);
        }
    }
    public void postData() {
        if (isPhotoTaken()) {
            if(AppStatus.haveNetworkConnection(_context)){
                if(_beenHere){
                    ImageUploader.uploadFile(getPhotoPath(),
                            "http://obo.nl/android-upload-image.php", Step4.this);
                } else {
                    for(String path : imageUploadList){
                        Debug.out(path);
                        ImageUploader.uploadFile(path,
                                "http://obo.nl/android-upload-image.php", Step4.this);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (_counter == 0) {
                    _counter++;
                    _activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(_context,
                                    getString(R.string.noInternetImageNotUploaded),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                    imageUploadList.add(getPhotoPath());
                }
                try {
                    if(_beenHere){
                        _beenHere = false;
                        goToNextIntent();
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }               
                postData();
            }
        }
    }

    private void goToNextIntent(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Step4.this, Step5.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, (Serializable) _user);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE2, _isRepairable);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE3, _injury);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE4, _category);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE5, _inch);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE6, _size);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        if(isPhotoTaken()){
            if(dialog != null){
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
        mailing(_isRepairable);
        new MyAsyncTask().execute(_mail);
    }
}
```

The line:

```
if(AppStatus.haveNetworkConnection(_context))
```

returns a boolean true if the user has a working internet connection. false otherwise.

What I want is to queue all the image paths (and mails sent afterwards) in the desired ArrayList so i can send them all at a later moment when the user has a working internet Connection. Please help me out!

Comment: can you please tell me how you done the part of upload once the network connection is back, I have done till store the values in shared preferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store your image paths in a list (or something similar) and persist the list, let's say in Shared Preferences. As you finish uploading a picture, you will remove it from that list and  continue to the next one, and so on until your list is empty.

While uploading, if the internet connection drops it will not affect you, you will always have persisted the list of images that are still to be uploaded.

Register a broadcast receiver to listen for wi-fi connection, when it gets connected it could automatically continue the upload - this is just a suggestion.

Comment: That would require a little bit of coding to do, too much copy/paste here; I could sketch something for you and make a Gist. do you use git?

Comment: I'm not using git, but do know how to use git so that's no problem for me :)